# Selenium undetected_chromedriver2 OSError: [WinError 6]

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

при работе с Selenium столкнулся с ошибкой:

```
Exception ignored in: <function Chrome.__del__ at 0x000001553085B380>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\maccr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver2\__init__.py", line 831, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\maccr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver2\__init__.py", line 786, in quit
OSError: [WinError 6] Неверный дескриптор
```

```py
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import undetected_chromedriver2 as uc

driver = uc.Chrome()
driver.get("link")
time.sleep(5)

log_in = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/button[1]/div')
log_in.click()

time.sleep(3)

phone_key = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="layoutPage"]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/section/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/label/div/div/input')
time.sleep(2)
phone_key.send_keys("nimber")
    
time.sleep(0.75)
login_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="layoutPage"]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/section/div/div/div/div/div[4]/button/span')
login_button.click
```

( использую undetected_chromedriver2 для обхода cloudflare )

В интернетах написали, что можно в **init**.py вставить

```py
try:
  time.sleep(0.1)
except OSError:
  pass
```

но во второй версии UC это уже сделано

с чес связана ошибка и как ее можно пофиксить?